# Delete all rows except 2 for each SID (descending order)

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, mysql-5.5

I have a table with this structure. For each SID there are different ITEMID

```
| sid | itemid |
|---| ---------|
| 1 | 20600    |
| 1 | 20598    |
| 1 | 20597    |
| 1 | 20596    |
| 1 | 20595    |
| 1 | 20594    |
...
...
| 2 | 19600    |
| 2 | 19598    |
| 2 | 19597    |
| 2 | 19596    |
| 2 | 19595    |
| 2 | 19594    |
...
...
```

What I need is to delete all but the last 2 rows with the ITEMIDs sorted in DESCENDING way.
This is the result I want to obtain:

```
| sid | itemid |
|---| ---------|
| 1 | 20600    |
| 1 | 20598    |
| 2 | 19600    |
| 2 | 19598    |
```

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Get 2nd value in subquery.

Comment: Hi @Akina, can you hel me to write it?

Comment: The subquery should by:
SELECT itemid FROM notifications_views_savedsearches_test ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t0
FROM test t0
JOIN ( SELECT t1.sid,
              ( SELECT itemid
                FROM test t2
                WHERE t1.sid = t2.sid
                ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1,1 ) itemid
       FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT t3.sid
              FROM test t3 ) t1 ) t4 USING (sid)
WHERE t0.itemid < t4.itemid;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c6d67da817ddbb9fb890693564bcd49c

Comment: you are my man! Thank a lot, It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can try a delete join using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sid, itemid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY itemid DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t2.sid = t1.sid AND t2.itemid = t1.itemid
WHERE
    t2.rn > 2;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, my mysql client version is 5.5.60

Comment: This query will be fairly difficult to do on MySQL 5.7 or earlier.